# Camel - unmarshal().serialization() - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to unmarshal with serialization method a bean that is not the current bundle but in a commons components bundle.

I get the following error when camel tries to unmarshal my bean :

> 22:43:11,865 | ERROR | nModule-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              | 89 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.8.0.fuse-06-11 | Failed
>   delivery for exchangeId: ID-ITEM-64684-49962-1354223882336-2-1.
>   Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commons.InformationInput
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commons.InformationInput    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)[:1.6.0_33]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.6.0_33]
>     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)[:1.6.0_33]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)[:1.6.0_33]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749334/osgi-bundle-access-spring-context-file-from-another-bundle
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_33]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:1610)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchDynamicImports(ModuleImpl.java:1547)

My bundle containing the bean is correctly started and i've defined the **commons** package in the **Export-Package** of the bundle definition

Does anyone managed to such thing ?

Comment: Which bundle in which bundle ? :) I've import packages from commons in bundle where camel route from unmarshalling is defined.

Comment: You should refine your question. What bundles are involved? Which bundle does what? What packages does each bundle import/export? Try to construct a minimal example, and then add that information to your question.

Comment: TO sum up : Bundle A defines a camel route which contains "unmarshal().serialization()". The bean to proceed throw this serialization is contained in a Bundle B (which contains only POJOs). Bundle A imports package of Bundle B POJOs and Bundle B export the same package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaroud by enabling dynamicimport on camel-core bundle.
This can be done on karaf console : `dev:dynamicimport <camel-core-bundle-id>`

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes occurs when the bundle that is serializing/deserializing classes does not know in advance what packages must be imported.

One workaround is to use [DynamicImport-Package](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package). For example:

```
DynamicImport-Package: *
```

This then means the bundle can import classes in any package, but beware of the costs (see the linked article).

Comment: I've tried to add this to my Bundle A (the one where camel route is defined) but it doesn't work as the problem happens in camel-core.

Comment: It needs to be in the bundle in which the class is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to Hibernate issues an OSGi environment where it fails because of class loading issues. I would recommend something classed class buddy loading. in the Manifest of your commons bundle that contains the class add this

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy:registered
```

Then in your dependent buddy make sure you have it added as a dependent bundle and this to its manifest.

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy:com.nameofmycommonbundle
```

This should solve your problem.

Here is a reference to hibernate [reference](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateAndEclipseIntegration)

Comment: Buddy class-loading is a feature of Equinox, it is not standard OSGi. (Still works, just wanted to add that information)

Comment: I've found a workaround but I'll try this solution as soon as I've got some time